# Displaying a large collection of large images

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

OK, I thought this was a fairly simple task, but apparently it isn't ...

I have a folder with +1000 photos in it. These are all photos taken with a camera, each about 3 MB. Users need to be able to view these pictures (as a list), rename or delete them. That's it.

A possible solution would be this control : [ImageListView - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43265/ImageListView)

but because it has an Apache license, we can't use it.

So how to do it? Any ideas or suggestions? I'm using .NET 2.0

.... EDIT : .....................................

OK, apparently we CAN use the Apache license. (Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007338/can-i-use-a-library-under-the-apache-software-license-2-0-in-a-commercial-applic) However, using the license is very confusing for me. I read the following guide but still don't exactly know how to apply it to  our project : http://blog.maestropublishing.com/how-to-apply-the-apache-20-license-to-your-pr

it says:

> you need two files in the root or top directory of your distribution.

What's exactly meant by 'distribution'? Is that our installed application, and top directory meaning Program files/OurApp/ ?

It also says:

> Replace all [bracketed] items in the above notice statement. There are only two of these items so should not be hard for you to do.

But that would give me a notice file, reading :

> Copyright 2012 OUR_COMPANY
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, etc...

But our app isn't licensed under the Apache license?

I'm sorry but I'm very confused and don't want to make any mistakes with this legal stuff...
What would I need to do exactly to be able to use this control?

Comment: What is wrong with `apache license`?

Comment: @L.B, I've seen some organizations against open-source projects, regardless of license, I suspect that's what's going on there.

Comment: Well it's a commercial application. Wouldn't we be required to make our app also (partially) open source?

Comment: @BigM: this has to be a functionality in our own app, we can't use windows explorer for that ..

Comment: @RunCMD AFAIK, Apache licence doesn't require that. You can use it anyway you want. There are many commercial applications using Solr,Hadoop,Lucene etc.

Comment: I am not an attorney but I don't read that license as requiring your app to be open source.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need your own control for this task.
What i think is just a sketch of what i`d do in your place.
You need your own control with paging(to show only limited photos to user) or scroll-event-driven(to load photos on demand).
Perhaps you need some thumbnail generator.

Point is you probably face a huge pile of photos, so you cannot get them all in one time.

Answer (score 0):

"Thats it" is not that simple.

For 1000+ that is over 3 GB.
Would need thumbnails for faster preview.

If users are going to access this files directly then they would need NTFS permission.
Maybe what you want.
What you  are going to get into in locking problems.
If one user has a file open then you cannot rename or delete it.

I know you are not going to like this but to do it right you need a server app to manage that folder and users access via a WCF service so there is a single control point.